# How can I determine if matplot lib axes have been turned off with axes.axis('off')?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

The following code snippet produces a line with no visible plot axes and a normal plot with visible axes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2)
ax[0].plot([0, 1])
ax[0].set_xlabel('x1')
ax[0].axis('off')

ax[1].plot([1, 0])
ax[1].set_xlabel('x2')
```

[image]

I would like a general way to detect whether the axes of a given `axes` instance are visible. I have tried a few things without finding a way to distinguish axes which are visible from those which are hidden by the above method:

```
for i in range(2):
    print('axes set', i, 
          ax[i].get_frame_on(), 
          ax[i].xaxis.get_visible(), 
          ax[i].xaxis.get_alpha())
```

Results:

```
('axes set', 0, True, True, None)
('axes set', 1, True, True, None)
```

As you can see, none of the outputs are different between the subplots with visible and invisible axes.

Given a set of `axes` objects which may or may not have been turned off with `.axis('off')`, how can I tell which ones are visible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`axison` attribute](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/1d45c08de2322e0de4d74572b09705fdbadcfa0d/lib/matplotlib/axes/_base.py#L2711) of the `Axes` object to determine whether the `axes` is turned on or off.

```
if ax.axison:
    print 'on'
else:
    print 'off'
```

Comment: I think shadowing the boolean datatype this way is a bit dangerous, as people often simply copy code from answers and then fall into traps.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest yup you're right. Wasn't thinking. Fixed now.

Comment: Don't worry, I didn't shadow the data type. :)